# sshでログイン時にPermission deniedと表示され、ログインできない

Tags: linux, ssh

```
ssh hogehoge@172.17.xxx.xx
hogehoge@172.17.xxx.xx's password: 
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Last login: Tue May 30 22:02:38 2017 from 172.31.25.73
Could not chdir to home directory /data01/home/hogehoge: Permission denied
-bash: /data01/home/hogehoge/.bash_profile: Permission denied
-bash-4.1$
```

ちなみに.bash_profile他のPermissionは下記の通り

```
[root@queen ~]# ls -al /data01/home/hogehoge
total 204
drwx------ 19 hogehoge snp   4096 May 15 13:46 .
drwxr-x--- 11 root  root   117 Apr  7 17:10 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    419 May 15 23:57 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp     18 Apr  7 17:04 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    176 Apr  7 17:04 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    391 Apr  7 17:04 .bashrc
drwxr-x---  8 hogehoge snp   4096 May 11 11:46 bin
drwxr-x---  3 hogehoge snp     20 Apr 13 15:21 .cache
drwxr-x---  4 hogehoge snp     56 May 15 09:53 .config
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    272 Apr  7 17:04 .cshrc
drwxr-x---  3 hogehoge snp     19 May 12 10:54 data
drwxr-x---  3 hogehoge snp     24 Apr 13 15:21 .dbus
drwxr-x---  2 hogehoge snp      6 Apr 13 15:21 Desktop
-rwxr-x---  1 hogehoge snp    500 Apr  7 17:04 .emacs
drwxr-x---  2 hogehoge snp      6 Apr 11 11:38 .felix
drwxr-x---  2 hogehoge snp    100 May 15 14:11 .filezilla
drwxr-x---  2 hogehoge snp      6 Apr 13 17:47 .gconf
drwxr-x---  2 hogehoge snp     24 Apr 13 19:08 .gconfd
drwxr-x---  3 hogehoge snp     19 Apr 13 15:21 .gnome2
drwxr-x---  2 hogehoge snp      6 Apr 13 15:21 .gnome2_private
-rwxr-x---  1 hogehoge snp     39 Apr  7 17:04 .i18n
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    171 Apr  7 17:04 .kshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    124 Apr  7 17:04 .mkshrc
drwxr-x---  5 hogehoge snp     51 Apr 13 15:21 .mozilla
-rwxr-x---  1 hogehoge snp     24 Apr  7 17:04 .mpd.conf
-rwxr-x---  1 hogehoge snp    256 Apr 13 15:22 .pulse-cookie
drwxr-x---  6 hogehoge snp     66 Apr  7 17:04 qsubsamples
-rw-------  1 hogehoge snp    429 Apr  7 17:04 .rhosts
drwx------  2 hogehoge snp     24 Apr  7 17:04 .ssh
-rw-------  1 hogehoge snp    102 May 15 13:46 .Xauthority
-rw-r--r--  1 hogehoge snp    658 Apr  7 17:04 .zshrc
```

どなたか、原因がお分かりの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

`ls`の出力を見ると、`/data01/home`ディレクトリの読み込み権(`r`)と実行権(`x`(ディレクトリ移動権))がないので、その影響でエラーが出ているように見えます。
付与すると事象が改善されると思います。
(`/data01`も同様であれば、同じように付与するとよいと思います)

```
【「/data01/home」(=「..」)の出力箇所】
[root@queen ~]# ls -al /data01/home/hogehoge
total 204
drwx------ 19 hogehoge snp 4096 May 15 13:46 .
drwxr-x--- 11 root root 117 Apr 7 17:10 ..
(以下、略)
```

なお、ログイン自体はできていると予想します。

Comment: 確かにご指摘の通りでした。Permissionを755に変更するとするりとディレクトリに移動できました。ありがとうございました。